# How to concatenate multiple lists element wise

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x, concatenation

Inputs:

```
l1 = ['a', '', '', '']
l2 = ['', 'b', '', '']
l3 = ['', '', 'c', '']
l4 = ['', '', '', 'd']
```

Expected output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I tried

`list(map(str.__add__, l1, l2, l3, l4))`

looks like `str.__add__` doesn't accept more than two list objects.

Any workaround ?

Edit: Based on  Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard comment.

```
l1 = ['a', '1', '', '']
l2 = ['', 'b', '2', '']
l3 = ['', '', 'c', '']
l4 = ['', '', '', 'd']
```

Expected output:

```
['a', '1b', '2c', 'd']
```

Thanks

Comment: `filter(None, l1+l2+l3+l4)` ?

Comment: what should the output be if other entries exist?

Comment: it shouldn't concatente other entries

Answer (score 12):

Seems like you need `zip`

```
[''.join(x) for x in zip(l1, l2, l3, l4)]
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

For the updated input:

```
[''.join(x) for x in zip(l1, l2, l3, l4)]
# ['a', '1b', '2c', 'd']
```